# Как изменить имя отправителя в mail() при использовании ssmtp?

Tags: php, linux, debian, email, smtp

Не как не могу разобраться с именем отправителя.
У меня nginx, debian, ssmtp, php

Отправляю письмо при помощи:

```
$to = "awikong@mail.ru";
$subject = "Заголовок";
$message = "<b>Привет</b>";

$headers = "Content-type:text/html; charset = utf-8 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: admin@boosteam.ru";
$headers .= "Reply to admin@boosteam.ru";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Но имя отправителя всегда одно и тоже: www-data

Как изменить имя отправителя?

Такие у меня настройки ssmtp.conf:

```
root=admin@boosteam.ru
rewriteDomain=boosteam.ru
mailhub=smtp.yandex.ru:465
hostname=boosteam.ru
UseTLS=YES
AuthUser=admin@boosteam.ru
AuthPass=*******
FromLineOverride=YES
```

revaliases:

```
root:admin@boosteam.ru:smtp.yandex.ru:465
UserUbuntu:admin@boosteam.ru:smtp.yandex.ru:465
www-data:admin@boosteam.ru:smtp.yandex.ru:465
```

В php.ini:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t
```

Comment: `$headers` - передавать в виде массива или строки, где отдельные заголовки склеены через `\r\n`, а тут в одной строке (`From:`) нет этого "клея"

Comment: @TotalPusher Вы хотите сказать нужно сделать так: $headers  = "Content-type:text/html; charset = utf-8 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: admin@boosteam.ru \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply to admin@boosteam.ru \r\n";

Comment: Если да, то проблема не ушла.

Comment: А там может быть несколько проблем. Первая - это. Вторая - настройки почтового серевера. С ssmtp я не знаком, может кто-то еще поможет.

Comment: Покажите итоговый `$headers`, который идет перед `mail()`

Comment: @TotalPusher $headers = "Content-type:text/html; charset = utf-8 \r\n";
 $headers .= "From: admin@boosteam.ru \r\n";
 $headers .= "Reply to admin@boosteam.ru \r\n";

Comment: Создайте файл `/tmp/dump.sh` следующего содержания: `#!/bin/bash` `cat - > /tmp/mail.eml` (получится файл на две строки). Затем `chmod +x /tmp/dump.sh`. Затем пропишите в php.ini: `sendmail_path = /tmp/dump.sh`. Затем перезапустите веб-сервер и отправьте пробное письмо из PHP. Приложите содержимое полученного файла `/tmp/mail.eml` в вопрос.

Comment: @TotalPusher Сделал как вы сказали, но перестали письма отправляться и файл /tmp/mail.eml не создался.

Comment: Странно, то что написал, должно создавать файл с содержимым письма, которое генерирует PHP. Попробуйте сделать `echo "foo" | /tmp/dump.sh` и затем `cat /tmp/mail.eml`. Какие ошибки это выдает? Вообще, скрипт и файл лежат в `/tmp`, он при перезагрузке очищается, но вы же перегружаете только веб-сервер, а не полностью весь сервер?

Comment: @TotalPusher Файла cat /tmp/mail.eml нет в папке. Я временно решил проблему так, указал  нужное имя для пользователя www-data.

Answer (score 1):

Я разделяю проблему на две части, нужно последовательно проверить следующее:

## 1. Ошибка на стороне PHP при подготовке писем

Посмотрим какие письма отправляются (нас в данном случае интересует поле `From:`).

Для этого в командной строке создадим файл `/var/tmp/dump.sh`, который будет дампить все письма, которые должны приходить MTA в файл `/var/tmp/mail.eml`. Этот файл будет содержать текст последнего отправленого письма.

```
tee /var/tmp/dump.sh > /dev/null <<\EOF
#!/bin/bash
cat - > /var/tmp/mail.eml
EOF

chmod 775 /var/tmp/dump.sh
```

Затем временно заменим в `php.ini` MTA:

```
sendmail_path = /var/tmp/dump.sh
```

Теперь нужно перезапустить веб-сервер (для cli-варианта этого делать не нужно) и отправить пробное письмо из PHP. Его текст можно получить так:

```
cat /var/tmp/mail.eml
```

Будет что-то похожее на это:

```
To: yyyyyyyy@site.ru
Subject: =?windows-1251?B?zvLx8/Lx8uLz5fIg4vvj8PPn6uA=?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 509:tools.php
From: XXXX <xxxxxxxx@site.ru>
Reply-To: xxxxxxxx@size.ru
...
```

Тут сразу можно выяснить правильность заголовка `From:`. Если заголовок верный, значит проблема на стороне MTA.

*Замечание*. Выяснить, какие `php.ini` используется можно так:

- для командной строки (SAPI интерфейс): `php --ini`
- для "www": разместить `phpinfo();` в скрипте

## 2. MTA неправильно отправляет письма

Вначале стоит убедиться, что используется именно тот MTA:

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 25
```

Получится что-то похожее:

```
tcp   0  0 127.0.0.1:25       0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      3483/exim4      
tcp6  0  0 ::1:25             :::*          LISTEN      3483/exim4
```

Обычно сразу пишется название запущенной программы (тут - exim). Если нет, ее можно выяснить по `PID`: `sudo cat /proc/3483/cmdline`

### sSMTP

[Пакет в Debian больше не поддерживается](https://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP)

Поправить файл `ssmtp.conf`:

- `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t -fname` - можно указать отправителя через `-fname`, но это будет работать только если не указывать в письме поле `From:` - не наш случай
- В файле `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` можно определить алиасы (для веба почта отправляется от пользователя, под которым запущен PHP, обычно это `www-data`) - не наш случай, так как включен `FromLineOverride=YES`
- `FromLineOverride=YES` (по-умолчанию опция закоментирована через `#`) - эта опция заставляет в качестве отправителя использовать заголовок `From:`, который был сформирован в PHP.

После изменения конфига необходимо перегрузить демона.

### EXIM

Exim может переписывать заголовки. Так можно проверить поведение правил перезаписи:

```
 exim -brw ph10@exim.workshop.example
```

Исправляется в секции `begin rewrite`. Обычно конфигурация находится в `/etc/exim/exim.conf`. Более подробно - в [документации](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-address_rewriting.html)